# Slow SQOOP 1 import due to rotating hadoop connection problems with YARN

Tags: apache, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, cloudera, sqoop

I'm working with Hive/Hadoop/Sqoop through the Cloudera 5.8.0 which includes sqoop 1.4.6. My Hadoop cluster has 4 Hadoop datanodes each with 16 GB memory and all are running ImpalaDaemons and Yarn NodeManagers. The Yarn server is running along with Hue, Hive and Sqoop2 on a server with 32 GB of RAM (has many roles).

Using Sqoop to import (from the main server  using Sqoop 1 via bash script to parquetfile format in a incremental job) from a MySQL database it seemed slow (50 seconds average) even when importing a table as little as 200 rows (or even 30 rows in one case). It would always hang (and finally succeed at the end) on this step on Sqoop for 30 seconds consistently even in Ubermode:

Notes: Clean Phase and repeats omitted for brevity..

`2016-11-03 10:07:50,534 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory: I/O error constructing remote block reader.
java.io.IOException: Got error for OP_READ_BLOCK, status=ERROR, self=/192.168.1.31:58178, remote=/192.168.1.34:50010, for file /user/(user profile name)/.staging/job_1478124814973_0001/libjars/commons-math-2.1.jar, for pool BP-15528599-192.168.1.31-1472851278753 block 1074078887_338652
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.RemoteBlockReader2.checkSuccess(RemoteBlockReader2.java:467)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.RemoteBlockReader2.newBlockReader(RemoteBlockReader2.java:432)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReader(BlockReaderFactory.java:881)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:376)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:662)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:889)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:942)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:85)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:119)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:369)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:265)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:357)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:356)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:60)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-11-03 10:07:50,541 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to connect to /192.168.1.34:50010 for block, add to deadNodes and continue. java.io.IOException: Got error for OP_READ_BLOCK, status=ERROR, self=/192.168.1.31:58178, remote=/192.168.1.34:50010, for file /user/(user profile name)/.staging/job_1478124814973_0001/libjars/commons-math-2.1.jar, for pool BP-15528599-192.168.1.31-1472851278753 block 1074078887_338652
java.io.IOException: Got error for OP_READ_BLOCK, status=ERROR, self=/192.168.1.31:58178, remote=/192.168.1.34:50010, for file /user/(user profile name)/.staging/job_1478124814973_0001/libjars/commons-math-2.1.jar, for pool BP-15528599-192.168.1.31-1472851278753 block 1074078887_338652
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.RemoteBlockReader2.checkSuccess(RemoteBlockReader2.java:467)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.RemoteBlockReader2.newBlockReader(RemoteBlockReader2.java:432)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReader(BlockReaderFactory.java:881)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:662)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:889)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:942)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:85)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:119)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:369)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:265)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:359)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:357)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:356)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:60)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-11-03 10:07:50,543 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient: Successfully connected to /192.168.1.33:50010 for BP-15528599-192.168.1.31-1472851278753:blk_1074078887_338652`

This error repeated 4 times.

When  ran the job again I got this:

`2016-11-03 10:37:38,093 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Start request for container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001 by user (user profile name)
2016-11-03 10:37:38,093 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Creating a new application reference for app application_1478124814973_0002
2016-11-03 10:37:38,095 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=(user profile name)     IP=192.168.1.34 OPERATION=Start Container Request       TARGET=ContainerManageImpl      RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1478124814973_0002    CONTAINERID=container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001
2016-11-03 10:37:38,096 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.Application: Application application_1478124814973_0002 transitioned from NEW to INITING
2016-11-03 10:37:38,096 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.Application: Adding container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001 to application application_1478124814973_0002
2016-11-03 10:37:38,106 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.AppLogAggregatorImpl: rollingMonitorInterval is set as -1. The log rolling mornitoring interval is disabled. The logs will be aggregated after this application is finished.
2016-11-03 10:37:38,134 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.Application: Application application_1478124814973_0002 transitioned from INITING to RUNNING
2016-11-03 10:37:38,138 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001 transitioned from NEW to LOCALIZING
2016-11-03 10:37:38,138 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event CONTAINER_INIT for appId application_1478124814973_0002
2016-11-03 10:37:38,147 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Created localizer for container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001
2016-11-03 10:37:38,148 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Writing credentials to the nmPrivate file /yarn/nm/nmPrivate/container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001.tokens. Credentials list: 
2016-11-03 10:37:38,149 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Initializing user (user profile name)
2016-11-03 10:37:38,151 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Copying from /yarn/nm/nmPrivate/container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001.tokens to /yarn/nm/usercache/(user profile name)/appcache/application_1478124814973_0002/container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001.tokens
2016-11-03 10:37:38,151 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Localizer CWD set to /yarn/nm/usercache/(user profile name)/appcache/application_1478124814973_0002 = file:/yarn/nm/usercache/(user profile name)/appcache/application_1478124814973_0002
2016-11-03 10:37:41,791 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory: I/O error constructing remote block reader.
java.io.IOException: Got error for OP_READ_BLOCK, status=ERROR, self=/192.168.1.31:39276, remote=/192.168.1.35:50010, for file /user/(user profile name)/.staging/job_1478124814973_0002/libjars/jackson-core-2.3.1.jar, for pool BP-15528599-192.168.1.31-1472851278753 block 1074079133_338898
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.RemoteBlockReader2.checkSuccess(RemoteBlockReader2.java:467)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.RemoteBlockReader2.newBlockReader(RemoteBlockReader2.java:432)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReader(BlockReaderFactory.java:881)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:376)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:662)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:889)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:942)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:85)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:119)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:369)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:265)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:359)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:357)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:356)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:60)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-11-03 10:37:41,792 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to connect to /192.168.1.35:50010 for block, add to deadNodes and continue. java.io.IOException: Got error for OP_READ_BLOCK, status=ERROR, self=/192.168.1.31:39276, remote=/192.168.1.35:50010, for file /user/(user profile name)/.staging/job_1478124814973_0002/libjars/jackson-core-2.3.1.jar, for pool BP-15528599-192.168.1.31-1472851278753 block 1074079133_338898
java.io.IOException: Got error for OP_READ_BLOCK, status=ERROR, self=/192.168.1.31:39276, remote=/192.168.1.35:50010, for file /user/(user profile name)/.staging/job_1478124814973_0002/libjars/jackson-core-2.3.1.jar, for pool BP-15528599-192.168.1.31-1472851278753 block 1074079133_338898
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.RemoteBlockReader2.checkSuccess(RemoteBlockReader2.java:467)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.RemoteBlockReader2.newBlockReader(RemoteBlockReader2.java:432)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReader(BlockReaderFactory.java:881)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:376)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:662)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:889)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:942)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:85)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:119)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:369)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:265)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:359)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:357)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:356)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:60)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-11-03 10:37:41,795 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient: Successfully connected to /192.168.1.32:50010 for BP-15528599-192.168.1.31-1472851278753:blk_1074079133_338898
2016-11-03 10:37:42,928 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001 transitioned from LOCALIZING to LOCALIZED
2016-11-03 10:37:42,951 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001 transitioned from LOCALIZED to RUNNING
2016-11-03 10:37:42,955 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: launchContainer: [bash, /yarn/nm/usercache/(user profile name)/appcache/application_1478124814973_0002/container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001/default_container_executor.sh]
2016-11-03 10:37:43,011 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Starting resource-monitoring for container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001
2016-11-03 10:37:43,034 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 25215 for container-id container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001: 1.4 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 103.6 MB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
2016-11-03 10:37:46,242 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 25215 for container-id container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001: 268.1 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 1.4 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
2016-11-03 10:37:49,261 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 25215 for container-id container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001: 398.4 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 1.5 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
2016-11-03 10:37:52,279 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 25215 for container-id container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001: 408.5 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 1.5 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
2016-11-03 10:37:55,297 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 25215 for container-id container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001: 416.6 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 1.5 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
2016-11-03 10:37:58,315 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 25215 for container-id container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001: 414.1 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 1.5 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
2016-11-03 10:38:00,934 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch: Container container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001 succeeded 
2016-11-03 10:38:00,934 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001 transitioned from RUNNING to EXITED_WITH_SUCCESS
2016-11-03 10:38:00,935 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch: Cleaning up container container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001
2016-11-03 10:38:00,967 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting absolute path : /yarn/nm/usercache/(user profile name)/appcache/application_1478124814973_0002/container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001
2016-11-03 10:38:00,968 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=(user profile name)     OPERATION=Container Finished - Succeeded        TARGET=ContainerImpl    RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1478124814973_0002    CONTAINERID=container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001
2016-11-03 10:38:00,968 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001 transitioned from EXITED_WITH_SUCCESS to DONE
2016-11-03 10:38:00,968 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.Application: Removing container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001 from application application_1478124814973_0002
2016-11-03 10:38:00,968 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.AppLogAggregatorImpl: Considering container container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001 for log-aggregation
2016-11-03 10:38:00,968 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Stopping container with container Id: container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001
2016-11-03 10:38:00,980 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=(user profile name)     IP=192.168.1.34 OPERATION=Stop Container Request
        TARGET=ContainerManageImpl      RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1478124814973_0002    CONTAINERID=container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001
2016-11-03 10:38:01,316 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Stopping resource-monitoring for container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001
2016-11-03 10:38:01,972 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Removed completed containers from NM context: [container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001]
2016-11-03 10:38:01,972 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.Application: Application application_1478124814973_0002 transitioned from RUNNING to APPLICATION_RESOURCES_CLEANINGUP
2016-11-03 10:38:01,973 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting absolute path : /yarn/nm/usercache/(user profile name)/appcache/application_1478124814973_0002
2016-11-03 10:38:01,973 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event APPLICATION_STOP for appId application_1478124814973_0002
2016-11-03 10:38:01,973 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.Application: Application application_1478124814973_0002 transitioned from APPLICATION_RESOURCES_CLEANINGUP to FINISHED
2016-11-03 10:38:01,973 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.AppLogAggregatorImpl: Application just finished : application_1478124814973_0002
2016-11-03 10:38:02,072 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.AppLogAggregatorImpl: Uploading logs for container container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001. Current good log dirs are /yarn/container-logs
2016-11-03 10:38:02,073 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting path : /yarn/container-logs/application_1478124814973_0002/container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001/stderr
2016-11-03 10:38:02,074 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting path : /yarn/container-logs/application_1478124814973_0002/container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001/stdout
2016-11-03 10:38:02,074 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting path : /yarn/container-logs/application_1478124814973_0002/container_e86_1478124814973_0002_01_000001/syslog
2016-11-03 10:38:02,160 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting path : /yarn/container-logs/application_1478124814973_0002`

After subsequent test it it having problems with nodes 3 and 4 (192.168.1.34 and 192.168.1.35).  The Cloudera interface says all nodes are healthy (I realize it may not be accurate). I can believe one might be bad (and tried decomminishing and deleting it and later recomminished it) but two seems odd, especially when I can query Impala or hive with no issues and Cloudera and fsck say the nodes are healthy.

I've run hdfs fsck on the root directory and no errors were found. Anybody understand why this is happening and better yet, can this be fixed?

Oh, it should be noted all nodes are virtual machines on the same physical server and all /etc/hosts files are configured to see all node hostnames (not using internal DNS for now). I've checked the iptables service on both 192.168.1.34 and 192.168.1.35 and ip tables is not running. Also verified that both machines are listening on port 50010.

Thanks All!

Answer (score 0):

Okay ,managed to get rid of the error. I changed this setting:

mapreduce.client.submit.file.replication

Setting this value to 4 (the number of yarn nodeManagers in the cluster,  it was 2 earlier) the I/O Exception error went away. As to speed, research indicates small tables with small files are handled inefficiently if Parquet format it used. So I'm guessing if I have smaller tables import intermediate tables are convert to HBase file format (or perhaps all of them as they are basically used as intermediate tables from raw sqoop import to native table format with timestamp columns (sqoop converts them to longint if using parquet format). If I make those Hbase I don't need to convert them anymore ironically.